# Cluster with categorical / ordinal

Tags: reductions, clustering, python

i have a dataset with movies review. I wish cluster my element but inside i have a 
categorical / ordinal values.

i seen that exist:

- MCA (Multiple Correspondence Analysis)
  https://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-MCA2007-pretty.pdf
- K-Models

I seen both the implentation in Python but seems not very used. (i seen poor example online).
Maybe i don't consider anyway some(maybe simple) way to do this stuff?

Anyone can clarify me on this type of classification?

Comment: What do you need clarified?  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: If exist a simple way to do this cluster, i m a bit lost with MCA and k-modes

Comment: 1. It sounds like you already have some ways to cluster this data.  I'm not sure why you have rejected those methods.  2. It's not clear what your requirements are.  There are probably hundreds of methods for clustering.  Without a clear statement of what your requirements are, why you can't use the standard methods, and how you propose to evaluate answers (by what metrics or criteria), I don't think the question is answerable.

Comment: My question is very general, because i just cluster numeric attribute, but i wish try to cluster categorical attribute. I don't know this two methods, i just find some on the web, but have very poor resource. @D.W.

Comment: If your question is very general, you should read [standard references on clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).  There's lots written on the subject and there is little point in us repeating that here.  If your question is "how do I cluster data with categorical attributes?", you should ask that question -- after doing that reading.